# How do I stop the page from continuous loading after getting the data

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a blog post and am fetching the comments based on the id of the blog i saved with the comments, anytime i want to fetch
the comments based on the id, it will work but my page will keep loading and i will see Cannot read property
'_id' of null on the console, whereas i have gotten the data i want.
How do i stop the page from still loading and why am i seeing this "Cannot read property '_id' of null" on console, after the getting the data???

here is the code

```
router.get('/articles/:slug', async (req, res) => {
    try {

     const singleBlog = await blogModel.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate('creator')
    //Fetch comments based on singleBlog Post
    const blogComments = await commentModel.find({ post: singleBlog._id }) 


        const category = await catModel.find()
        const catCount = []
        for(let i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
                const countIt = await blogModel.countDocuments({category: category[i].catname});
                catCount.push({name:category[i].catname, count:countIt});    
        }
        
        return res.render('front/blog_details', {
            singleBlog,
            blogComments,
            catCount, category
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }

})
```

Comment: can you check whether the for loop had finished before you send response.

Comment: When I comment out the for loop still have the same thing